# How do I submit a button on AJAX response data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my code I make a call to get a HTML page. It then returns it. I want to try and "click" this button so the function inside the href attribute is carried out.

This is the HTML code for the button:

```
<a id="ctl00_cphRoblox_ClaimOwnershipButton" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphRoblox$ClaimOwnershipButton','')">Claim Ownership</a>
```

this is my script

```
$.get("https://www.roblox.com/My/Groups.aspx?gid=34877", function(r){
//click button here

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a div with e.g. id="mydiv" that contains the html, so you can click it:

```
$.get("https://www.roblox.com/My/Groups.aspx?gid=34877", function(html){
        //show and embed html
        $('#mydiv').html(html);
        //click button here
        $('#mydiv').find('#ctl00_cphRoblox_ClaimOwnershipButton').click();
    });
```

Comment: @AmazingAaron nice that you mark an answer as the right one when it's not working...